# MySQL change engine on tables with Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

So, in the process of creating our tables, we weren't paying close enough attention to our system and all of the tables were created with the `InnoDB` engine. This is really only bad because we want to have a `FULLTEXT` index on a few of the columns.

So, now I want to convert. And while I'm at it, I just want to convert all the tables to `MyISAM` so that if we ever add columns in the future that we want to index, we have that option. So I've got my .sql file with the following:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName1 Engine = MyISAM;
ALTER TABLE tableName2 Engine = MyISAM;
```

However, when I try to run it, I get the following error:

> Error Code: 1217 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

As you might have guessed, we have foreign keys in our tables. Not my style, but also not my department, nor my creation script.

My question boils down to, is there anyway for me to change the engine on these tables without having to wipe the DB?

**Edit:** Note that this will need to be done on multiple development and test copies of the database, so something I can script would definitely be preferred.

Comment: Can you remove the FKs without the application breaking? Or just implement something better like Solr for the fulltext indexing?

Comment: @ceejayoz Removing the FKs is an option, but not really what I would like since we have a lot of tables. I would have to go through each table, find the foreign keys and delete them manually. And this would be across multiple dev and test servers. I'd like a way to do it without having to do that. Also, Solr isn't really an option.

Comment: If you're looking for a simple, no work solution, I think you're going to be disappointed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to my knowledge, sort of but not really.  mysqldump the database and edit out the foreign key constraints in the dumped sql file.  And of course change the engine in the CREATE TABLE script.

Comment: That is an option I'd considered, but I will have to do this on multiple databases, so something I can script is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB unlike MyISAM support foreign keys and has lots of great features like transactional system that ensures integrity across all tables. MyISAM tables tend to fail now and then when you have large data in tables or for many other reasons.
In the near future InnoDB will implement FullText search. I recommend not to change tables' engine but have something like Sphinx in place. Sphinx is much more powerful and much more flexible than Fulltext Search which works for InnoDB.

More about fulltext search in InnoDB:
[InnoDB Fulltext search](http://drdobbs.com/database/231902587)

Comment: Sphinx is not an option. My host doesn't allow long running or always-on processes.